# Is there a way to put a kind of identificator to asychronous requests?

Tags: java, asynchronous, client-server

I have a server and a client that sends requests. I don't need to identify the requests when it works in synch mode. But in asynch mode each request must have an identificator, so I could be sure that the response corresponds to exact request. The server is not to be updated, I have to put the identificator in the client's code. Is there a way do do it? I can't find out any.

Here is my main class. I guess all must be clear, the class is very simple.

```
public class MainAPITest {
    private static int userId = 0;
    private final static int NUM_OF_THREADS = 10;
    private final static int NUM_OF_USERS = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Security.addProvider(new GammaTechProvider());
        ExecutorService threadsExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_USERS; i++) {
            MyRunnable user = new MyRunnable();
            userId++;
            user.uId = userId;
            threadsExecutor.execute(user);
        }
        threadsExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    int uId;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            abstrUser user = new abstrUser();
            user.setUserId(uId);
            user.registerUser();
            user.chooseAndImplementTests();
            user.revokeUser();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

User class describes the user's behaviour. It is long enough, idk if it is needed here. User runs a number of random tests. Each test has its own class that extends abstract test class, where the http connection is established:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;

public abstract class abstractRESTAPITest {
    protected String apiUrl;

    public abstractRESTAPITest() {
    }

    protected byte[] sendRequest(JSONObject jsonObject) throws IOException {
        return this.sendRequest(jsonObject, (String) null, (String) null);
    }   

    protected byte[] sendRequest(JSONObject jsonObject, String username, String password) throws IOException {  
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(this.apiUrl)).openConnection();
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()));
        }

        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("REST send: " + jsonObject.toString());
        if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("REST send error, http code " + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() + " " + httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage());
            throw new IOException();
        } else {
            byte[] responseBody = null;
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data.append(line);
                responseBody = data.toString().getBytes();
            }

            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            return responseBody;
        }
    }   

    public abstract boolean test();

}
```

Now I am trying to transform the httpUrlConnection part of the code into a kind of this.

```
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

var httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(new URI(apiUrl))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonb.toJson(jsonObject)))
        .build();

client.sendAsync(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

It must send a JSON request and receive JSON response. HttpClient, introduced in Java11, has sendAsync native method, so I try to use it. But I don't understand fully how it works, so I have no success.

Comment: Its not clear what kind of communication protocol is between client-server. What client library are you using for async?

Comment: I am trying to use HttpClient, that was introduced in JDK11 and has native async functions.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, this will give idea of your code setup. Usually, with async calls, you get a future, which can be waited to get response. Depending on how you are setting up your calls and futures there might be a way to associate a future with original request and hence the response.

Comment: Alright, I've edited the description above and added the code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, but I am not seeing any async calls here. On the side, to clarify, you want the async calls to be identified on the server side for some reason?

Comment: Thanks you, Ajay M. I've added above the demonstration of my attempts to use the asycn calls. Regarding your question, I just need to identify the responses from the server to be sure they are sent from the server for the exact request. E.g. I send requests A, B, C, D and I receive responses W, X, Y, Z responsively. It works fine if the calls are sync. But if they async, how can I be sure that response W came for request A? It can come for any other request I send, and I have to check it. I suppose that sendAsycn does it itself - but I am not sure about it - it is just an assumption.